# C# dynamically create a stack of combined controls in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Lets say I have two classes:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = null;
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Foo(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Foo[] FooArray { get; set; }
    public Bar(Foo[] fooArray) { FooArray = fooArray; }
}
```

Using `Bar` as input, I would like to dynamically create a stack of controls containing a `label` and a `combobox` for each `Foo` in `FooArray` where the label shows the `Name` property and the `combobox` can be used to set the `Value` property to one of the available values in another array.

```cs
var possibleValues = new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
var bar = new Bar(new Foo[] { new Foo("Foo1"), new Foo("Foo2"), new Foo("Foo3") });
```

I would like the result to look something like this:

[image]

How could I set such a thing up?

Comment: Well you'd create the controls in a loop and add them to a panel or whatever... have you tried anything yet? What happened? It's much easier to help you if we can see how far you've got already.

Comment: I don't really know where to start in winforms. I know how to do it in WPF with a `ListBox` and `DataTemplate` which automatically stacks them when you bind to a list of objects. But what kind of control would I use with winforms?

Comment: "I don't really know where to start in winforms." Then I'd suggest that reading a tutorial on Windows Forms should be your next step... then try creating what you'd expect using the designer, so you can work out which controls you want, for example... and convert that into code. Someone just giving you a lot of code you don't understand isn't going to be useful, IMO.

Comment: Frankly, if you already know WPF I'd recommend not taking the step backwards to use Winforms. But if you insist, I do agree that your question lacks important details, making it too broad. That said, Winforms features you should look at: `UserControl`, which can be used as a sort of "poor man's template" (i.e. design a `UserControl` specific to the `Foo` object), and the `FlowLayoutPanel` control, which will allow you to add instances of your `UserControl` and have them automatically lined up/stacked.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for the tips. Going back to winforms is not a choice in this case unfortunately. Just for future questions, what kind of detail does my question lack? I thought I had included all neccesary information and an example of what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand what you are saying, but I have worked with winforms before. It's just that I'm looking for a direction to solve this particular problem in a robust and reusable way. Just starting to read random tutorials won't help me I believe, I wanted to get some tips on which direction to start searching in.

Comment: Then it's *really* unclear what you'd expect an answer to look like. Going from "I don't really know where to start in winforms" to "I have worked with winforms before" makes it very hard to understand what you're looking for. If you've worked with WinForms before, what's stopping from doing what I suggested in my very first comment?

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay, in retrospect I understand that  "I don't really know where to start in winforms" is not actually a question and doesn't make clear what I'm looking for. I was basically looking for a direction to search further. I have thought about just adding the controls in a loop, setting their position manually, but this doesn't seem really like a robust and reusable way to me (especially the manual position setting). There must be a way to stack custom controls, I just wasn't able to find the right search terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel) inside a [GroupBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.groupbox).

And use this function to generate the components dynamically.

```
...
tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 0;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
foreach (var foo in bar.FooArray)
{
    AddTableChildControl(new Label
    {
        Text = $"{foo.Name}:",
        Font = new Font(DefaultFont.FontFamily, DefaultFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
    });
    var combo = new ComboBox();
    combo.Items.AddRange(possibleValues);
    combo.SelectedValueChanged += delegate
    {
        foo.Value = combo.SelectedItem as string;
    };
    AddTableChildControl(combo);
}

void AddTableChildControl(Control control)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount++;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(control, 0, tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1);
}
...
```

**EDIT** I wanted to add a full generation function.

```
Control GenerateFooBarUi(Bar bar, params string[] possibleValues)
{
    var table = new TableLayoutPanel
    {
        RowCount = 0,
        ColumnCount = 0,
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    };
    table.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

    foreach (var foo in bar.FooArray)
    {
        AddTableChildControl(new Label
        {
            Text = $"{foo.Name}:",
            Font = new Font(DefaultFont.FontFamily, DefaultFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
        });
        var combo = new ComboBox
        {
            Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 10)
        };
        combo.Items.AddRange(possibleValues);
        combo.SelectedValueChanged += delegate
        {
            foo.Value = combo.SelectedItem as string;
        };
        AddTableChildControl(combo);
    }

    var groupBox = new GroupBox
    {
        Text = "Available Foo's",
        Padding = new Padding(10),
        Width = 10, //--very small value,
    };
    groupBox.Controls.Add(table);
    
    groupBox.Height = table.GetRowHeights().Sum() + groupBox.Padding.Vertical + groupBox.Font.Height;
    groupBox.Width = table.GetColumnWidths().Max() + groupBox.Padding.Horizontal;

    return groupBox;

    void AddTableChildControl(Control control)
    {
        table.RowCount++;
        table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        table.Controls.Add(control, 0, table.RowCount - 1);
    }
}
```

Finally you can use the dynamic control like this:

```
...
var control = GenerateFooBarUi(bar, possibleValues);
//set position
control.Left = 10;
control.Top = 10;
//add to controls collection
Controls.Add(control);
...
```